# How to change data type of columns without dropping it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT(
DEPARTMENT_NAME VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
BUDGET_CODE INT NOT NULL,
OFFICE_NUM INT NOT NULL, 
PHONE NUMERIC NOT NULL ,
);
```

I have this table that I am creating but i want to change budget code and office number in varchar instead of int. Is there a way to do this. this table is linked to other tables with foreign key. So i can't drop it and create a new one.

Comment: What type of SQL server is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.DEPARTMENT
ALTER COLUMN BUDGET_CODE VARCHAR(100)
ALTER COLUMN OFFICE_NUM VARCHAR(100)
```

Comment: i get this error

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'COLUMN'.

Actually it worked. 
Thanks much